# MacOS find: illegal option -- n

Tags: find

To preface, I'm very new to using the Mac terminal and SRA Toolkit. I used the following command to download sra files from NCBI using SRA Toolkit

```
prefetch -O output_directory --option-file SRR_Acc_List.txt
```

This worked but the command I tried using to download the sra files as fastq files did not

```
find -name \*.sra -exec bsub fastq-dump --split-3 --gzip {} \;
```

It gives me this error:

```
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

Comment: In the *usage* message reported by your `find` implementation, the optional parts are in `[...]` square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it at least one directory/file to search in. Assuming you want to search in the current working directory, you can use `.`. So try

```
find . -name '*.sra' -exec bsub fastq-dump --split-3 --gzip {} \;
```

The implementations of `find` usually found on Linux-based operating systems (GNU, busybox or toybox `find`), default to using the current directory (a behavior allowed but not required by the POSIX specification of the standard `find` utility), so you may have seen many examples with `find -name ...` online.

However, the version of `find` that ships with macOS (FreeBSD `find`) requires you to specify at least one search directory/file explicitly either as `find that-file` or `find -f that-file` (the latter being a BSD extension that allows passing arbitrary file paths while the `find that-file` version would fail for file paths starting with `-` or that happen to match predicate names).

Comment: Hi! I tried the commands you suggested but it still won't work. For this command:    find /Users/lucykelly/Desktop/Assel_paper/output_directory -name "*.sra" -exec bsub -n 4 -o output.log -e error.log ./run_fastq_dump.sh {} \;                                                                           it gives the error:                                                                                                               find: bsub: No such file or directory

Comment: @LucyKelly that's a completely different issue. That means that the `bsub` executable isn't in your `$PATH`, in the list of directories where the system expects to find executable files. Only programs stored in those directories can be executed by name in the terminal. For others, you would need the full path (e.g. `/som/directory/name/bsub` instead of `bsub`). You can ask a new question about that, either here or perhaps on [bioinformatics.se] where the folks who work with these programs are more likely to hang out.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `bsub` is a command [to submit jobs to a cluster](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/what-are-bsub-command-options-and-flags). I am guessing you found the command you're running in some tutorial but that was about working on a cluster. I suspect you want `find . -name '*.sra' -exec fasterq-dump --gzip {} \;` See https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/08.-prefetch-and-fasterq-dump